# остановить скрипт php из javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Как прекратить или остановить выполнение функции php из javascript?

Comment: Никак. Поверьте, это не то, что Вам надо.

Comment: Опишите цель, что именно хотите, возможно есть другой способ решения

Comment: @ThisMan реализую progress-bar выполнения скрипта в пхп. По кнопке старт запускаю скрипт пхп аяксом и получаю данные о прогрессе. Далее нужно по нажатию на другую кнопку остановить выполнение скрипта пхп

Comment: В чем тогда проблема? Отправляете запрос, начинаете показывать прогресс бар, после того как пришёл ответ от сервера убираете прогресс бар